# Why the hard disk of my cloud and the online version will differ in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

Why the hard disk of my cloud and the online version will differ in Google Drive?

Comment: Are you sure the two are in sync with each other?

Answer (score 0):

There have been some syncing issues between online Drive UI and the installed app. They usually get synced after a while.